# How can I block incoming SMS from certain senders?

Tags: sms-blocking

What is a good app for blocking incoming SMS? I want it to be easy and able to add numbers from contacts and not require to many privileges (probably only some storage and intercepting SMS).

Answer (score 2):

'Call & SMS Filter'. I've not used it but description matches what you are after & very good comments.
I believe Handcent SMS also has block options.

Required privileges on both are greater than your preference though.

Answer (score 2):

I found SMS Filter, that only intercepts messages and requires no privileges. It doesn't allow to add number from contacts though.