# Blocking messages from a particular contact

Tags: sms-blocking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good app for blocking incoming sms?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2198/good-app-for-blocking-incoming-sms)

how can i temporarily block all messages in an ANDROID operated Dell Streak by a particular contact....

Comment: Was it something she said? ;)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can with the default SMS app.

The 2 best alternatives, HandCent SMS & [GoSMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jb.mms) offer a feature called blacklisting - you can long-press hold a conversation and choose to add it to your blacklist. Such messages will be hidden (not deleted) and you won't receive notifications / popups.

You can also configure individual notification colour and ringtone for a particular user.

Answer (score 2):

Your carrier may be able to block the contact for you.  For example, [here is how you would do it on Verizon.](http://wirelesssupport.verizon.com/features/top_questions.html?t=3#item12)

Comment: +1, you can also often text the number to short-code "SPAM" or similar.  (And with my vote, your rep is now OVER 9000!!)

Comment: IT'S OVER 9000!!!!! :)