# SMS rules application

Tags: sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good app for blocking incoming sms?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2198/good-app-for-blocking-incoming-sms)

There is a service number that always sent me sms messages. 10 or 20 times in a day.
Can you suggest an app. for creating a rule for that number ( just ) so no notification will be showed ?

regards..

Comment: Whoever closed this question, it would be great if you could provide a link to or at least the question title of the duplicate question.